# Unacceptable type of value for attribute with int value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, core-data, nsnumber

I work with core data and I try to assign an int value (id) from WS to core data attribute (Integer 32) . The attribute is an NSNumber and when I code it :

```
        NSNumber *v = [responseMembers valueForKey:@"id"];
        newMember.idMember = v;
```

And, this error appears :

> ```
> 2013-06-17 11:08:24.407 EPNet[2190:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable
> ```
>
> type of value for attribute: property = "idMember"; desired type =
>   NSNumber; given type = __NSArrayI; value = (
>       1,
>       2,
>       3,
>       4,
>       10,
>       14,
>       17,
>       5,
>       6,
>       7,
>       8,
>       9,
>       11,
>       12,
>       13,
>       15,
>       16,
>       18,
>       19,
>       20 ).'

Can you help me please ?

Comment: show the declaration of `idMember`.

Comment: The declaration generated by xcode: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * idMember;

Comment: What's `responseMembers` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Property idMember is a `NSNumber`, but for some reason the value for your key `@"id"` seems to be an array (looks like there where all ids in it?)

edit:
responseMembers is a `NSMutableArray`, you should not be able to ask for a `valueForKey`. Try something like this instead:

```
foreach (NSDictionary *member in responseMembers)
{
    NSNumber *v = [member valueForKey:@"id"];
    //do something with this id
}
```

the json you are reading looks like an array with many dictionaries, and your ids are one layer deeper:

```
[
  //first member
  {
    "content": "some entry",
    "id": 5,
    // some more attributes
  },
  //second member
  {
    "content": "some entry",
    "id": 5,
    // some more attributes
  },
  //and so on
]
```

Comment: The WS is : http://epnet.fr/news.json and I keep the "id" value . Why is an array and not NSNumber values? @Herm

Comment: With AFN : `NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.epnet.fr/members.json"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        NSMutableArray *responseMembers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        responseMembers = JSON;
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Failed Response : %@", JSON);
    }];
    [operation start];`

Comment: @Benjamin: `responseMembers` is an array of many dictionaries, and each dictionary contains an "id" value. `[responseMembers valueForKey:@"id"]` is then an array containing all the ids. Which of the many ids do you want to assign to `newMember`?

Comment: Ok. So, for each member, I have to create a dictionnary like this :         `NSMutableArray *dicoNew = [responseMembers objectAtIndex:i];` but it doesn't works... @Herm

Comment: no, you have to create a dictionary like `NSDictionary *dicoNew = [responseMembers objectAtIndex:i];` you got the type declaration wrong.

Comment: I'm an idiot. It's because there is simply no value. It will work, thanks

Comment: you have to look carefully at the structure of the JSON. "facebook" is a node unter `member`. You have to create a dictionary from the key "member" first. use a JSON formatter like jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com to format the JSON readable. Then you'll see where the nodes are exactly.